# My internet connection slows or dies unexpectedly

Tags: networking, wireless

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 once again and I'm having some problems which I had before, but I have no idea how I solved them.

On Windows, everything's working fine and I had no problems with this.

My problem is that sometimes, when browsing through the internet, webpages just start to load really slow, sometimes it doesn't load anything at all (`Error 118 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.`) and it starts to work after few minutes.

My IPv4 settings are automatic (DHCP), and IPv6 settings are Ignored/Disabled. I think my previous problems had something to do with IPv6, but I'm not sure.

Is there a fix for this?

iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Fsite1"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: C8:3A:35:40:43:68   
          Bit Rate=0 kb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple answer for this.

`iwconfig` said me that "Power management" is on. Which is causing troubles. To turn that off, simply put this into console

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```